# why the recording file is empty in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, pyaudio

I am trying to record my desktop screen and record the audio from microphone simentensously with the help of this python script.

Now when i run only the screen capture part the code works perfectly fine but when i try to run both sound recording and screen capture combine code as shown in below code. my video and audio both file does not open. (0 bytes) or very less size file.

How can i solve this  problem.

> updated Code

now i am able to record voice properly but the video file is not opening?

```py
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk ,FLAT
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading
import win32api
import pyaudio
import wave

VIDEO_SIZE = (800 , 420)  #(960, 540)
p = ImageGrab.grab()
a, b = p.size
chunk = 1024 
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16 
channels = 2
fs = 44100 
frames = []
g = pyaudio.PyAudio() 
date = datetime.datetime.now()
filename='rec_%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s.mp4' % (date.year, date.month, date.day,date.hour, date.minute, date.second)
  #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
frame_rate = 24
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out = cv2.VideoWriter() 
def screen_capturing():

    global capturing
    capturing = True

    while capturing:

        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        frame = np.array(img)
        sc = np.array(img)
        _xs,_ys = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        cv2.circle(frame,(_xs,_ys),20,(255,255,0), 2)
        sc = cv2.resize(sc, VIDEO_SIZE)
        tkimage.paste(Image.fromarray(sc))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        out.write(frame)
def start_screen_capturing():

    if not out.isOpened():

        out.open(filename, 0x31637661, frame_rate,(VIDEO_SIZE))
    t1=threading.Thread(target=screen_capturing, daemon=True)
    t1.start()

def stop_screen_capturing():
    global capturing
    capturing = False
    out.release()

def voice_recording():
    global recording
    while recording:
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)

def start_voice_recording():
    global stream 
    stream = g.open(format=sample_format,channels=channels,rate=fs,frames_per_buffer=chunk,input=True)
    global recording
    recording = True
    print('capturing')
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=voice_recording)                # daemon=True
    t2.start()

def stop_voice_recording():
    #global recording

    recording =False 
    print(' complete')
    filename='test'    
    filename = filename+".wav"
    wf = wave.open(filename,'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(g.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Screen Recorder')
root.geometry('+260+70')

tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', VIDEO_SIZE, (0,0,0)))

w, h = VIDEO_SIZE
vbox = tk.Label(root, image=tkimage, width=w, height=h, bg='black')
vbox.pack(pady=10,padx=25)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

start_cap = tk.Button(frame, text='Start screen Recording', width=30, command=start_screen_capturing)
start_cap.grid(row=0, column=0)

stop_cap = tk.Button(frame, text='Stop screen Recording', width=30, command=stop_screen_capturing)
stop_cap.grid(row=0, column=1)

start_voice = tk.Button(frame, text='Start voice Recording', width=30, command=start_voice_recording)
start_voice.grid(row=0, column=2)

stop_voice = tk.Button(frame, text='Stop voice Recording', width=30, command=stop_voice_recording)
stop_voice.grid(row=0, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there no one who can answer my query?

Comment: Have some patients. Many of the people that could answer your question may be in different time zones sleeping or at work. That said you posted a lot of code. Please reduce it down to the basic problem. For example do you need all those buttons? Do you need all those icons? we don't have those files so what do you expect us to do? Instead just leave text in the labels/buttons that use those icons.

Comment: You have issues with local variables. For example `stream` is defined in your `startrecording` function adn then you try to call it in your `record` function. However `stream` is only ever defined in the function so anything outside of `startrecording` cannot see it. You will have to make it a global variable. You have some indention problems in `start_recording` as well as a confusing naming convention as you later call a function `startrecording` and this could lead to calling the wrong functions by mistake if your not careful.

Comment: `start_webcam` and `stop_webcam` are referenced in `change_w` but those 2 functions do not exist in your example. `tkimage` is not defined but is references as well in multiple places.

Comment: You define it in the global namespace however in the function `stoprecording` that update it it is only defined locally and not globally. You will have to add `global isrecording` to each function that updates `isrecording`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT sorry my mistake actually my code is bigger than this so i elemated some part of it (the webam function) while posting. (code updated) check.

Comment: @Mike-SMT now the voice is recording sucessfully but my microphone is still on in the background after clicking the stop_voice button also and the video file is corrupted.(low size in bytes)